# How to override a function in a package?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a package from `biopython` called `SubsMat`, I want to override a function that is located in SubsMats `__init__.py`.

I tried making a class that inherits `SubsMat` like this:

```
from Bio import SubsMat 
class MyOwnSubsMat(SubsMat):
```

but you cannot inherit a package I guess. I cannot alter the source code literally since it is a public package on the network.
Is there any workaround for a noob like me?

Comment: How do you intend to use `MyOwnSubsMat`? Only in your own code? Or do you intend to replace the functionality when using that `biopython` package?

Comment: I'd like to replace the functionality when using that biopython package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that:

```
from Bio import SubsMat 
SubsMat.function = my_own_replacement_for_function
```

But it will change the package for everyone using it.